# ionic3 Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error for android and ios build , this works fine with "ionic serve"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-httpclient

how to fixed the issue of cross origin request requested from android and ios builds if ionic3. I am able to access  the same en points using ionic serve from the browser, but as i try to take the production build and access the endpoints i am getting the above error.

Also i even tried the ssl server test check where i am getting this "Assessment failed: No secure protocols supported". I am not getting how to fix this. Does any one face the same issue ? or knows how to tackle this .....

i have imported

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and set the headers with

```
   headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', "application/json");


 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.http.post(TASK.BASEURL + task, requestData, { headers: headers, params: extraParams })
                  .map(res => res)
                  .subscribe(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                  }, error => {
                    reject(error)
                  });
              });
```

-----------------------------------Error Log ---------------------------------

11-27 18:09:55.919 5813-10986/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: false
11-27 18:09:55.985 10808-10808/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost:8080/#/login: Line 0 : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
11-27 18:09:55.985 10808-10808/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.", source: http://localhost:8080/#/login (0)
11-27 18:09:56.454 7163-7182/? I/Finsky: [1422] com.google.android.finsky.bp.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: BlockingExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bp.ao@afe5f2f[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 7]
    [1422] com.google.android.finsky.bp.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: LightweightExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bp.ao@ca9093c[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 55]
11-27 18:09:56.500 7163-7182/? I/Finsky: [1422] com.google.android.finsky.bp.an.run(6): Stats for Executor: bgExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bp.ao@53166c5[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 9]

Comment: I removed the [tag:cors] tag because neither of the errors cited in the question are CORS errors.

Comment: how you can use it in browser using ionic serve. may be you are using angular http in browser?

Comment: Yeah I am using same httpClient from angular.

Comment: oh can you put your code in question ?

Comment: also screenshort of error log

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';




sendPostRequest(){

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }), 
  params: extraParams
}; 

return this.http.post("url", bodydata); 
              
}



//call method 
callPostmethod(){
sendPostRequest.subscribe((response)=>{
//success
console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(response)); 
}, (error)=>{
//error
console.log("erorr"+JSON.stringify(error)); 
})
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, i just seen your error log. it is cors issue. Ref https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: but it is cors issue because I also face issue many time. I have fixed in server.

Comment: How did you fixed it in server ? Can you put some guidelines, bcoz its nailing me out

Comment: sorry i don't manage server side. you talked with your backedn developer to fix cors issue.